# Javascript Promise Chain to Retrieve Value From Website

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I have the following Javascript code in order to extract the "Current Order Rate" from "incoming.shopify.com".  However, when I pull the source HTML, the source HTML is so long that it does not incorporate that "Order/Minute" figure on the website.  I would like to extract the "Order/Minute" figure from the source HTML and print it out using console.log.

```
var wd = require('wd');
var fs = require('fs');

// defaults
var browser_name = 'firefox';

wd.configureHttp({
  timeout: 60000,
  retries: 3,
  retryDelay: 100
});

var browser = wd.promiseChainRemote();
var p = { promise: null };

/*** Expose Components to other files ***/
exports.browser = browser;
exports.p = p;

// setup
p.promise = browser
  .init({ browserName: browser_name })
  .setAsyncScriptTimeout(30000)

p.promise = p.promise
    .get("incoming.shopify.com")
    .sleep(1500)
    .source(function(err, source_html){
      var FindNumberArr = source_html.split('<div class="counter__count" id="volume_rate">');
      var Result1 = FindNumberArr.slice(1);
      var FindNumberArr2 = Result1.split("</div>");
      var Result2 = FindNumberArr2.slice(0);
      console.print(Result2);
    })

p.promise = p.promise
  .quit()
  .done();
```

Comment: The initial HTML has the counter as '--'.  It must be set somewhere in the JS, either way you cannot do a get on it to get the initial number.

Comment: thanks @MatTaylor.  Do you know which road I should go down in order to programmatically get this number?

Comment: I tried having a look at where it decides this number.  I couldn't see any XHR requests being fired off though, so may be deeply referenced in some JS somewhere.